# Eclipse plugin development IDE question

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am trying to develop some simple Eclipse plugins. I am having some problems with my IDE when I try to add new extensions in my manifest. I created a sample plugin project. I selected MANIFEST.MF file and then opened it in editor. I switched to extensions tab and added new extension "org.eclipse.ui.command". When I right click on the newly added extensions, I get "New" -> "Generic". But tutorial says I would be seeing "org.eclipse.ui.command" specific options like "activeWhen", "category", "command" etc. Also when I try to click on "Show extension point description", I get an error. It looks similar to java development when javadoc is missing for the external jar. Should I need javadoc for the plugins too. Or Is there any specific preference which I am missing? I have PDE plugin installed correctly. I am using Eclipse 3.5. If you have any solution, please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not having the source bundles. Which package did you download? [See here](http://eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) to know which one has the source bundles and which one doesn't.